# Spring Cloud Contract for Webflux Reactive APIs

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to apply Spring Cloud Contract to a Reactive API built with Spring Webflux. Basically be able to send a Flux and receive a response Flux from an API in the style of:

```
@RequestMapping("/endlessecho")
public Flux<String> endlessEcho(Flux<String> input) {
    return input;
}
```

I can however find no information online or in the documentation on whether I can do this with Spring Cloud Contract.

Is it even possible to write a Contract for this? Will it be able to feed wiremock and generate the appropriate JUnit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this commit (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/commit/f7030148a9337d4c7184f7c8e27c271d9b89681b) I've added a WebFlux example to the Spring Cloud COntract Samples.

It's enough to define the contract as usual, pass the `EXPLICIT` mode for `testMode` parameter in the plugin setup. Instead of `RestASsuredMockMvc` you have to use the standard `RestAssured` static `URI` field to set up the URI of the app that is using `WebFlux`. You need to setup the whole Spring Context and bind to a port and that's pretty much it.

In the project called `consumer` there's a test that uses the stubs from the `producer-webflux` project. From the Stub Runner's perspective, there's no change in how the stubs are started.