# Spring cloud contract for rest api exposed in producer side using apache cxf in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, cxf, spring-cloud-contract

We are using a spring boot project which expose its services using Apache cxf, and has no controller layer in it. We want to test those Rest apis which the producer creates at the producer side with Spring Cloud Contract. How can we achieve it?

Comment: Resolved refering this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/49915858/15010856.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Cloud Contract for Webflux Reactive APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885765/spring-cloud-contract-for-webflux-reactive-apis)